# Detect when Xamarin Scrollview has reached the end

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin forms to display a list of items in a scrollview. I would like to add a feature so that when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page I can trigger an event (ex. load more items). Currently, I am using this OnScrolled Function to trigger the loading event:

```
private void OnScrolled()
        {
            if (Scroller.ScrollY >= (Scroller.ContentSize.Height -Scroller.Height)+1)
            {
               //load more items

            }
        }
```

The problem is that this function gets called multiple times even though the page has only been scrolled to the bottom once. Any tips on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 6):

The method will be called multiple times, because your are using an event handler for the scroll changed.

```
 private void OnScrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
        {
            MyScrollView scrollView = sender as MyScrollView;
            double scrollingSpace = scrollView.ContentSize.Height - scrollView.Height;

            if (scrollingSpace <= e.ScrollY) // Touched bottom
                // Do the things you want to do
        }
```

Comment: Worth noting, sometimes it is good to put a value of say `1` for error in calculation.

Comment: IMPORTANT: If `ScrollView` has top or bottom `Padding`, must subtract those from `scrollingSpace`.

Answer (score 0):

Your method, it should not be used.
There are a few things that might be helpful:

- ListView's Event => [ItemAppearing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.itemvisibilityeventargs.-ctor?view=xamarin-forms#xamarin-forms-itemvisibilityeventargs-ctor(system-object-system-int32)).
  Calculate itemIndex to load more.
- CollectionView => [use `ReamainingItemsThreshold` & `ReamainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand` to raise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data#load-data-incrementally)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).