# Xamarin Forms: How to detect the scrollview(or expander) end or top reached?

Tags: xamarin.forms, scrollview, expander

I need to load more data when scrollview reaches the end or top. I found the same [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51369639/detect-when-xamarin-scrollview-has-reached-the-end) over here, but on that, I didn't understand what is `MyScrollView`.

```
private void OnScrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
{
    MyScrollView scrollView = sender as MyScrollView;
    double scrollingSpace = scrollView.ContentSize.Height - scrollView.Height;

    if (scrollingSpace <= e.ScrollY)
    {
       //reached end
    }
}
```

I implemented the same in `ListView` using the `ItemAppearing` event. But currently, I am using `Expander` on the UI to display data. Is there any same kind of event for the expander to reach the end and beginning? The expander is inside of a scrollview, that's why I started researching about the scrollview end event.

How can I trigger some kind of event when scrollview reaches end or beginning?

### Update

My scrollview contents are like below, it contains `BindableLayout` and `Expander`.

```
<ScrollView
    x:Name="MyScrollView"
    Scrolled="OnScrolled">
    <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems,Mode=TwoWay}">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander>
                </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: i can be wrong, but didn't you asked the same thing on Xamarin Forum a few years ago? https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/111449/load-more-items-without-button-click also James Montemagno has a great blog post about it: https://montemagno.com/load-more-items-at-end-of-listview-in/

Comment: It suddenly struck me a moment ago that what you're looking for is an infinitely scrolling content loader, like some websites have (e.g. Instagram). It turns out there's at least one plugin that should help.

See here: https://xmonkeys360.com/2021/01/04/xamarin-forms-infinite-scroll-listview-lazy-loading

If you follow the example you can see where you can put your expanders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the question I have implemented the same feature in `ListView` using the `ItemAppearing` event. But in this case, my data is a list of items inside another list. That's why I forced to use the `Expander` component to display the data on the UI.

At the same time, I need to load more items when the `Expander` bottom reaches. But `Expander` doesn't provide the related event because it is not a scrollable control. So that I tried to find out an event for the `ScrollView` component. But no luck for that also.

Finally, I decided to change the data to a single list from a list inside another list. I have converted that using some for loops and now the data is suitable for `ListView`. And I have implemented the load more feature using the `ItemAppearing` event.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MyScrollView is probably a custom view using ScrollView. Here is my sample code using the Listview. You can apply this to your custom scrollview as well.

CustomListview.cs

```
public class CustomListView : ListView
{
    public CustomListView()
    {
    }
}
```

iOS

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomListView), typeof(CustomListViewRenderer))]
namespace YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class CustomListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Element != null)
            {
                Control.AlwaysBounceVertical = Element.IsPullToRefreshEnabled;
                Control.Bounces = Element.IsPullToRefreshEnabled;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Element.IsPullToRefreshEnabled))
            {
                Control.AlwaysBounceVertical = Element.IsPullToRefreshEnabled;
                Control.Bounces = Element.IsPullToRefreshEnabled;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Android

```
No custom renderer is needed
```

Xaml

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0"
              x:Name="DashboardBarGrid"
              BackgroundColor="#263A43"
              RowSpacing="0">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Row="0"
                  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="Title" TextColor="White"/>
            </Grid>

        </Grid>
         <controls:CustomListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Scrolled="listView_Scrolled" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="False"/>
     </Grid>
```

Page.cs

```
...
private Animation _lastRowAnimation;
private readonly double _initialLastRowHeight;
private readonly RowDefinition _lastRowDefinition;
private bool _isScrolled;
private bool _isFirstRun;
public List<string> Items { get; set; } = new List<string>();
...

public MyPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   _lastRowDefinition = DashboardBarGrid.RowDefinitions[0];
   _initialLastRowHeight = _lastRowDefinition.Height.Value;
   _isFirstRun = true;
            
   Items.Add("A");
   Items.Add("B");
   Items.Add("C");
   ...
   Items.Add("Z");

   BindingContext = this;
}

...
private void listView_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
{
   var listView = (ListView)sender;
   if (e.ScrollY > 50) _isFirstRun = false;
   if (_isScrolled && e.ScrollY == 0 && _lastRowDefinition?.Height.Value < _initialLastRowHeight){
      listView.IsEnabled = false;
      _lastRowAnimation = new Animation((d) => _lastRowDefinition.Height = new GridLength(d.Clamp(50, double.MaxValue)), _lastRowDefinition.Height.Value, _initialLastRowHeight, Easing.Linear, () => _lastRowAnimation = null);
      _lastRowAnimation.Commit(this, "Animation", 16, 500, Easing.Linear, (v, c) =>
      {
         _isScrolled = false;
         listView.IsEnabled = true;
      });
   }


   // Hide the rows
   else if (!_isScrolled && _lastRowDefinition?.Height.Value >= 
   _initialLastRowHeight && !_isFirstRun)
   {
      listView.IsEnabled = false;
      _lastRowAnimation = new Animation((d) => _lastRowDefinition.Height = new GridLength(d.Clamp(0, double.MaxValue)), _initialLastRowHeight, 0, Easing.Linear, () => _lastRowAnimation = null);
      _lastRowAnimation.Commit(this, "Animation", 16, 500, Easing.Linear, (v, c) =>    {
         _isScrolled = true;
         listView.IsEnabled = true;
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the question with some other details, could you please have a look?

Answer (score 0):

Your original code is on the right track. It took me some fiddling some time ago to get it working but here's the code I use. It's a lot simpler than that MyScrollView class.

```
private void TheScrollView_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
{
    if (TheScrollView.ScrollY >= TheScrollView.ContentSize.Height - TheScrollView.Height)
    {
        //All the way to the bottom.
    }
    else if (TheScrollView.ScrollX <= 0)
    {
        //All the way to the top.
    }
    else
    {
        //Neither all the way to the top nor to the right.
    }
}
```

Comment: tried this, the bottom `if` part is not firing. Always firing the top `else if` part.

Comment: I have updated the question with some other details, could you please have a look?